# Unable to merge the custom records in salesforce

Tags: apex, merge

I couldn't merge the custom SObject records. It shows an error like

```
Specified type Candidate__c cannot be merged
```

My Code is :

```
// Account creation code

List<Candidate__c> newCandidateList = new List<Candidate__c>();
Candidate__c c1 = new Candidate__c();
c1.Years_of_experience__c = 4;
c1.Last_Name__c = 'Oracle';
c1.First_Name__c = 'Inc.';
newCandidateList.add(c1);

Candidate__c c2 = new Candidate__c();
c2.Years_of_experience__c = 14;
c2.Last_Name__c = 'Oracle Inc';
c2.First_Name__c = 'Inc.';
newCandidateList.add(c2);

Candidate__c c3 = new Candidate__c();
c3.Years_of_experience__c = 24;
c3.Last_Name__c = 'Oracle Inc';
c3.First_Name__c = 'India';
newCandidateList.add(c3);

insert newCandidateList;
system.debug('Insert List are :' + newCandidateList);


// Merging code
Candidate__c childrecords = [
        SELECT Id,
          Name,
          First_Name__c,
          Last_Name__c,
          Years_of_experience__c
        FROM Candidate__c
        WHERE First_Name__c = 'Inc.'
        LIMIT 1];
system.debug('Retrieved Child Records are :' +childrecords);

Candidate__c masterecord = [
        SELECT Id,
        Name,
        First_Name__c,
        Last_Name__c,
        Years_of_experience__c
        FROM Candidate__c
        WHERE First_Name__c = 'India'
        LIMIT 1];
system.debug('Master Records :' + masterecord);

try{
    merge masterecord childrecords;    
} catch (Exception de){
    system.debug('Error during merging the records :' + de.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce will allow you to use `merge` operation on Account, Contact, and Lead.

As of now, I am not entirely sure if SF is supporting the merge of custom object records. It appears from this [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrPe) that it is still under consideration.

There is an app you can use directly from the [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/) and it's called [Dupe Eliminator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000178g7EAA).

Answer (score 2):

There are only 3 objects that support merge: Account, Contact, and Lead.

See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_examples_merge.htm), under "Merging Considerations"